# Actionscript: replace straight quote with smart quote?

Tags: actionscript

Is there a simple way to replace straight quotes with smart quotes (curly quotes?)

I've tried:

```
var the_string = example.text;

example.htmlText = the_string.replace("\"", "&quot;");
```

But it doesn't appear to make the quotes curly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking to replace text within quotes using the left and right double quotation mark entities:

```
“ = &#8220;
” = &#8221;
```

Using regex, this could be accomplish such as:

```
var the_string:String = "\"This\" is the \"text\".";

trace(the_string.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, "&#8220;$1&#8221;"));
```

This example would produce:

> “This” is the “text”.

Comment: Thanks this explains a lot. Does the plus sign express unlimited characters?

Comment: Plus sign is repetition, attempting to match the preceding token once or more.

Comment: I adapted this for PHP: `preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '&#8220;$1&#8221;', $text);` Now how to nest another regex within this to replace simple single quotes with curly apostrophes...hmm.